# How do I create a `Scheduler` for `observeOn` method?

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, observable, rx-java

I'm using RxJava in my Scala project and I need to execute my `Observable` in a separate thread. I know in order to achieve this I need to call `observeOn` method on it and pass an instance of `rx.lang.scala.Scheduler` as an argument.

But how can I create that instance? I did not find any apparent ways of instantiating of `rx.lang.scala.Scheduler` trait. For example, I have this code:

`Observable.from(List(1,2,3)).observeOn(scheduler)`

Can someone provide an example of working `scheduler` variable that will do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trait is not instantiable.

You need to use one of the subclasses of the trait listed under "Known Subclasses" in the [API documentation](http://rxscala.github.io/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

All schedulers are in the package

```
import rx.lang.scala.schedulers._
```

For blocking IO operations, use IO scheduler

```
Observable.from(List(1,2,3)).observeOn(IOScheduler())
```

For computational work, use computation scheduler

```
Observable.from(List(1,2,3)).observeOn(ComputationScheduler())
```

To execute on the current thread

```
Observable.from(List(1,2,3)).observeOn(ImmediateScheduler())
```

To execute on a new thread

```
Observable.from(List(1,2,3)).observeOn(NewThreadScheduler())
```

To queues work on the current thread to be executed after the current one

```
Observable.from(List(1,2,3)).observeOn(TrampolineScheduler())
```

If you want to use your own custom thread pool

```
val threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(threadPoolExecutor)
val customScheduler = ExecutionContextScheduler(executionContext)
Observable.from(List(1,2,3)).observeOn(customScheduler)
```